# writing a query using advanced group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single table database consists of the following fields:
ID, Seniority (years), outcome and some other less important fields.
Table row example:

```
ID:36     Seniority(years):1.79   outcome:9627
```

I need to write a query (sql server) in relatively simple code that returns the average outcome, grouped by the Seniority field, with leaps of five years (0-5 years, 6-10 etc...) with the condition that the average will be shown only if the group has more than 3 rows.

Result row example:

```
range:0-5    average:xxxx
```

Thank you very much

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you the king? I didn't vote for you...

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` statement to create different age groups. Try this

```
select case when Seniority between 0 and 5 then '0-5' 
            when Seniority between 6 and 10 then '6-10' 
            ..
       End,
       Avg(outcome)
From yourtable
Group by case when Seniority between 0 and 5 then '0-5' 
            when Seniority between 6 and 10 then '6-10' 
            ..
         End
 Having count(1)>=3
```

Since you have decimal places, If you want to count `5.4` to `0-5` group and `5.6` to `6-10` then use `Round(Seniority,0)` instead of `Seniority` in `CASE` statement

Comment: I like the idea because I need to keep it simple, without creating more tables. But is there a way to divide it into groups more effiently? Becasue if my MAX seniority is 60 I'll need to write 12 cases and it becomes a bigger problem if I have a large number of rows and I don't know the MAX seniority

Answer (score 0):

This would be something like:

```
select floor(seniority / 5), avg(outcome)
from t
group by floor(seniority / 5)
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Note:  This breaks the seniority into equal sized groups which is 0-4, 5-9, and so on.  This seems more reasonable than having unequal groups.

Comment: Won't work... `1.79 / 5 = 0.358000`. You need to cast to int I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow *Gordon*'s answer(but you should to edit it a little), but I would do this with additional table with all possible intervals. You then can add appropriate index to boost it.

```
create table intervals
(
    id int identity(1, 1),
    start int,
    end int
)

insert into intervals values
(0, 5),
(6, 10)
...


select i.id, avg(t.outcome) as outcome
from intervals i
join tablename t on t.seniority between i.start and i.end
group by i.id
having count(*) >=3
```

If creating new tables is not an option you can always use a `CTE`:

```
;with intervals as(
                    select * from 
                    (values
                            (0, 5),
                            (6, 10)
                            --...
                    ) t(start, [end])
                  )
select i.id, avg(t.outcome) as outcome
from intervals i
join tablename t on t.seniority between i.start and i.[end]
group by i.id
having count(*) >=3
```

Answer (score 0):

P.s.
0-5 contains 6 values while 6-10 contains 5.

---

```
select        'range:' 
            + cast (isnull(nullif(floor((abs(seniority-1))/5)*5+1,1),0) as varchar) 
            + '-' 
            + cast ((floor((abs(seniority-1))/5)+1)*5 as varchar)     as seniority_group

           ,avg(outcome)

from        t

group by    floor((abs(seniority-1))/5)

having      count(*) >= 3
;
```